# Duplicate elements in a hashset

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, hashset

I have a problem with hashsets at the moment. I have classes which are immutable and contain just one item, when I add two different classes with the same data to a hashset, I get them both in the set. This is weird, because I've overloaded Equals and GetHashCode on both the base class and the superclass.

```
public abstract class Contact :IEquatable<Contact>
{
    public readonly BigInteger Id;

    public Contact(BigInteger id) { this.Id = id; }

    public abstract bool Equals(Contact other);

    public abstract int GetHashCode();

    public abstract bool Equals(object obj);
}
```

And the inheriting class:

```
public class KeyOnlyContact :Contact, IEquatable<KeyOnlyContact>
{
    public KeyOnlyContact(BigInteger id) :base(id) { }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is KeyOnlyContact)
            return Equals(obj as KeyOnlyContact);
        else if (obj is Contact)
            return Equals(obj as Contact);
        else
            return (this as object).Equals(obj);
    }

    public override bool Equals(Contact other)
    {
        if (other is KeyOnlyContact)
            return Equals(other as KeyOnlyContact);
        else
            return (this as object).Equals(other as object);
    }

    public bool Equals(KeyOnlyContact other)
    {
        return other.Id.Equals(Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
```

As you can see, all the real work is deferred to the BigInteger which is the id. This is a .net class and I have confirmed I don't get duplicate if I just add BigInteger to a hashset.

To clarify:

```
BigInteger a;
HashSet<Contact> set;

set.add(new KeyOnlyContact(a));
set.add(new KeyOnlyContact(a));

set.Count == 2
```

Comment: BTW, turn on warnings, and you should see: "Warning [n] 'Foo.GetHashCode()' hides inherited member 'object.GetHashCode()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword."

Comment: I have got warnings on, unfortunately I also have warnings about non commented public methods, which is an ongoing task which keeps burying useful warnings in annoying documentation warnings. I think I might change that option!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public abstract int GetHashCode();
```

You have accidentally re-declared `GetHashCode` (method-hiding). Remove this declaration and it might start working. When your derived classed `override GetHashCode`, they are providing *this* version - they *aren't* overriding `object.GetHashCode`, which is what is required.

If you want an abstract `GetHashCode`, perhaps:

```
public sealed override int GetHashCode() { return GetHashCodeImpl(); }
protected abstract int GetHashCodeImpl();
```

Now the derived types *must* provide `GetHashCodeImpl`, and they are all mapped to `object.GetHashCode`.

Comment: bah, that hides the method rather than requiring that inheriting classes implement it themselves. I'll go and see if that fixes it

Comment: Yes it does. And this is what I get for coding at silly times in the morning on the train :( Thanks very much Marc

Comment: Can I not say public override abstract int GetHashCode(); to fix it and require that overriding classes provide their own hashcode?

Comment: @Martin - do you know what - I've never thought to try that, and it seems to work fine. Good show!

Comment: Woah :O I was expecting you to come back with a reason that looked good but was in fact a terrible idea ;)